# "typo3temp/compressor" folder in TYPO3 grows 1 GB per day

Tags: typo3

I have take over the management of a TYPO3 webpage, and Ive realized that everyday that goes by, it grows 1GB in CSS and JS files alone, "merged-ffff2d33c1ce910940054845fe400023.js" and so. Right now my compressor folder is 15GB big. It's huge!

It seems as if the CMS made a cache version of the CSS and JS with each page hit, but I'm just guessing as I have no idea of what's going on in this folder.

I've compared the files on each subpage, and while some commonalities are found, there's still many lines of difference.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start to compare javascript files merged.

Can you tell me what is the difference ?

For example there can be a case when some javascript is generated with page id like

```
<script>
var pageId = 77;
</script>
```

If there is option turn on to move inline javascript to external file then this will be different for each page and finally merger will create new merged version for every page.

So the most important question for now is what is the difference beetwen merged files.

EDIT: The solution for you would be to remove all third part extensions. Clear the /compress/ folder. Then install those third party ext one by one and see which one is causing the problems.

Comment: Ive compared the files and while they have quite common areas, they also have many lines of difference (around 100 lines)

Comment: Could you paste the diffrence ?

Comment: Is it safe to delete the files in the folder "compressor" manually?

Comment: Sure. Its safe. Its safe to remove all files and folders in typo3temp/ manually and clear the cache for the whole website. The only drawback is some performance issues becase TYPO3 needs to rebuild all that files.

Comment: I think I will turn off the concatenation alltogether. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I am quite sure its not tee problem of core and mostly used extensions as I never faced this problem. This must be done by some rare third party extensions.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I set

```
concatenateJs = 1
concatenateCss = 1
compressJs = 1
compressCss = 1
```

in my typoscript. The problem is that TYPO3 seems to have a bug in compressing the JS and CSS files. I tested with 6.2.10.
With every request from every user/browser TYPO3 generates a new CSS file in typo3temp/compressed every day.
Deactivating compression

```
compressJs = 0
compressCss = 0
```

solves the problem and TYPO3 always delivers the same cached CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the CSS genereated by CSS Styled content is actually aware of which elements are on each page. So if one page has an image with text on the right, the needed styles for this is included, and if another page does not have an image with text on the right, this CSS is not generated. This results in the CSS actually being different on almost all pages, resulting in many merged CSS files.

I'm missing an option to just include all the CSS, not matter if its used or not. This might create a substantially larger CSS file, but at least it will be the same file on alle pages, and thus cacheable in the browser.